# How to set title of aspx page from user defined controller in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Is it possible to set title of ASPX page from user defined controller like from ASCX page?

Little explanation, I am calling some services from User defined controller, So I am just trying to set Title of main page from controller(ASCX)

Is it possible?
If not What would be other way to do this?

-Vishal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UserControl` has a property `Page`, a page has a property [`Title`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.title%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so ...

```
this.Page.Title = "Hello World";
```